# close() on shared memory in osx causes invalid argument error

Tags: c, macos, shared-memory

The following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *p;
    int shm_fd;
    int error;
    size_t len;
    if ((shm_fd = shm_open("/somename", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666)) < 0) {
        perror("shm_open");
        exit(1);
    }
    error = close(shm_fd);
    if (error < 0) {
        perror("close");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Works fine on fedora22 x86_64, freebsd 10.2 x86_64. But it fails on OSX 10.10 with

```
close: Invalid argument
```

What is wrong with the call on OSX?

Comment: There is no difference regarding the `shm_open` or `close` statement requirements in either OS. The only way the error makes sense is if `shm_fd` is `0` or (negative). You check for the negative case, so that leaves the `0` case not checked. It is hard to say based on what you have posted. Why not change your `shm_open` check to `<=` and see if  `shm_fd` is being returned as `0` for some reason.

Comment: <=0 comparison makes no difference. I checked it, and shm_open returned 3, but close() returned an error nevertheless.

Comment: Same results here. I've looked at the man pages for both Linux and OSX and your usage is fine. So the only thing I can suggest is to run the code through both `gdb` and `valgrind` and see if they may shed more light on the issue. My results are the same as yours on Linux. I have no OSX to test on.

Comment: Have you tried `mmap()`ing it between the `open` and `close`? Maybe there is some implicit assumption you would use the memory that you are falling foul of. Just a thought :-)

Comment: Thanks for your ideas.
It turned out, that if you call
`ftuncate(shm_fd, any_size_even_zero)`,
`close` works well.
However, as you can call it on a particular shm_fd only once in osx, this behaviour seems to be strange.
I cannot open a shared memory object, do not use it, and close.

Comment: Anyway, this does not explain, why `close()` falis on osx without `truncate`. If somebody has any ideas, please share.